# Exported CSV from MySQL doesn't appear in specified directory

Tags: mysql, export, csv

I'm trying to figure out the syntax to export the results of a MySQL query to the desktop as a CSV file via SSH. Here's what I'm trying:

```
 SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'C:\Users\Jim Smith\Desktop\zyzyz.csv'
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
 OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'  
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
 from <table> limit 5;
```

The query itself works fine, but the file doesn't appear on the desktop. What should I change to get it to show up?

Answer (score 0):

In windows use \\ or / while using in path of file. your command should be as follow

> SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'C:\\Users\\Jim Smith\\Desktop\\zyzyz.csv'
>   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
>   OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
>   LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
>   from  limit 5;

or

> SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'C:/Users/Jim Smith/Desktop/zyzyz.csv'
>   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
>   OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
>   LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
>   from  limit 5;

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, and also under Windows - security rules make hard to write into user folders (even when application run by LoalSystem). Better to create folder on disk c:\ in root, c;\uptput and redirect query for this folder